# How do I display the contents of a Linked List in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, I created a linked list class and added a bunch of values. But I don't know how to display those values.

I tried doing the following:

```
System.out.println(list);
```

But it printed out some weird values like `ADTList@` followed by some jibberish.

Comment: If you create your linked list by extending `AbstractSequentialList` you get the desired behaviour for free, as it's implemented by the grandparent `AbstractCollection`.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(Object o : list){
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"ADTList@(followed by some jibberish)" is created by the default `toString()` method. Override this to print something useful. This may require overriding in both the list implementation and the elements.

Assuming that `ADTList` is your own implementation of a linked list, it's `toString` method could look something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Iterator<Object> i = iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext()) {
        return "[]";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        Object element = i.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : element);
        if (! i.hasNext()) {
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        }
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

This has been copied from the JDK's `AbstractCollection` class, as Christoffer Hammarström mentioned in his comment. It adds characters to make it list-like, e.g. "[x,y,z]" and also handles the list containing itself.

It might also be worth mentioning that the 'gibberish' in the default `toString` does actually have meaning. It is the name of the class the object is an instance of, and the hexadecimal value of object's `hashCode` - where the default `hashCode()`, will represent a memory location.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to iterate through all the items in your linked list and print their values, or else, override the `toString` method for each of your items.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get an **Iterator** on that list by invoking **iterator()**. Then call **next()** to get the elements until **hasNext()** returns false.

```
Iterator<Object> i = list.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
    System.out.print(i.next()+"\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate it to see the contents.

```
for(Object obj : list) {
  System.out.println(obj);
}
```

But your Object needs to have .toString() overriden.

Comment: +1 `System.out.println(obj);` is enough, since `println()` will call `toString()` internally.

Comment: that is correct. i will edit my response

Comment: I did that however It tells me I can only iterate over an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can print each value performing a for each loop on the list :

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
//Fill the list 

for (String s : list)
     System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your own implementation of a linked list (any reasons why you would do that?), you also need to override the default behavior of `toString()` if you want to print the content of the list in a user friendly way.

If you use the `LinkedList` provided in `java.util`, then the line of code you show in your question will print as expected.

Comment: Thank You!! I added a toString method to both my Node and the ADTlist class and it just works! Thank you specifically and everyone else as well!

Answer (score 0):

Override the `toString` method and write your own implementation to print useful Info About the same.

```
public String toString(){
   System.out.println("*** CONTENTS ***");
   for(Object obj: this){
     System.out.println(obj);
     //May be you will be required to override toString in your custom domain class to make it more useful
   }

   System.out.println("*** ******** ***");
}
```